# Comparing pooled propotions for a meta-analysis

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, proportion, meta-analysis, pooling

For a meta-analysis, I have pooled single proportions (complication rates and reoperations) of 5 treatment methods separately using a random effects model . Now I would like to compare the 4 pooled treatment modalities with the pooled golden standard separately by using the chi-squared test 4 times. Is this the best statistical method?

```
drf <- read.csv("drf.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
##
drf <- drf[, 1:5]
names(drf) <- c("study", "type", "treat", "events", "n")

compl <- subset(drf, type == "Complications")

reop <- subset(drf, type == "Reoperations")

library(netmeta)

n.compl <- netmeta(compl, reference = "PC", comb.random=TRUE)
n.compl

netgraph(n.compl, iterate = TRUE, number = TRUE)

n.reop <- netmeta(reop, reference = "PC", comb.random=TRUE)
n.reop

netgraph(n.reop, iterate = TRUE, number = TRUE)
```

A part of the dataset:

```
Study| Event Type| Treatment| Number of Events (n)| N| n/N|
Kumaravel| Complications| EF| 3| 23| 0,1304348|
Franck| Complications| EF| 2| 20| 0,1|
Schonnemann| Complications| EF| 8| 30| 0,2666667|
Aita| Complications| EF| 1| 16| 0,0625|
Hove| Complications| EF| 31| 39| 0,7948718|
Andersen| Complications| EF| 26| 75| 0,3466667|
Krughaug| Complications| EF| 22| 75| 0,2933333|
Moroni| Complications| EF| 0| 20| 0|
Plate| Complications| IMN| 3| 30| 0,1|
Chappuis| Complications| IMN| 4| 16| 0,25|
Gradl| Complications| IMN| 12| 66| 0,1818182|
Schonnemann| Complications| IMN| 6| 31| 0,1935484|
Aita| Complications| IMN| 1| 16| 0,0625|
Dremstrop| Complications| IMN| 17| 44| 0,3863636|
Wong| Complications| PC| 1| 30| 0,0333333|
Kumaravel| Complications| PC| 4| 25| 0,16|
```

Comment: @Peter Flom thank you for your help. Isn't t question if the chi squared test is the right test to compare the pooled proportions(complication rates) a on topic question?

Comment: Yes. But you asked about R code and that is off topic.

Comment: @Peter Flom I have deleted the R code sentence

Comment: This remains somewhat hard to follow without reading the code, which is itself hard to read b/c it's a picture. Can you make it a little clearer &/or type your question as text, not just post a photograph (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/))?

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no" as it would be better to model all your studies in one analysis using treatment as a five level moderator in a meta-regression. But given your fairly brief description that is just a supposition on my part.

Comment: @gung I changed the question and deleted the picture. Hopefully I changed it for the better.

Comment: @mdewey how would I do that? Just a linear regression with what as the dependent and what as the independents?

Comment: As has already been mentioned in comments this site is not about R code and I have already given you hints about where to look in my comments on your other questions about this data-set.

Comment: @mdewey What is wrong with comparing the 4 treatment modalities separately?

Comment: A model with all the data would usually have more precise estimates and would also give you an overall test of equality of all the five conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61120/discussion-between-rotterdam-and-mdewey).

Comment: @subhash c. davar My hypothesis is that the pooled proportions do not differ significantly.                                                                                          The output I had after synthesizing the data using the random effects model were 24.87% for EF(95% CI 12.91% to 42.49%), 20.45% for IMN(95% CI 12.54% to 31.54%), 23.46% for KW (95% CI 12.00% to 40.79%), 17.77% for PC (95% CI 10.53% to 28.42%) and 10.63% for VPO(95% CI 2.13% to 39.43%).

Comment: DO you have 4 treatments or 5  treatments?  for a gold standard ? Further why do you choose chi - squared test.?

Comment: IS one of  five treatments being considered as Gold standard ? What is your end objective ? I may succeed in answer for the problem.

Comment: @subhash c. davar yes, PC (one of the treatments). I want to compare the treatment methods with a random effects model and want to see if they are different or not.

Comment: @Rotterdam Which random effects  model did you implement for output.Further, I am not able to make out whether you want a comparison of each of 4 groups with gold standard treatment or alternatively you want to test that there is no difference in effect of each of 5 treatments ?

Comment: @subhash c. davar the mixed effects model is the default setting of the code I used, I tried to change it to a random effects model but wasn't able to. I would like the 4 other treatments to be compared to PC and see if there is a significant difference in one of the 4 comparisons.

Comment: You seem to have computed the estimates by using random - effects model correctly. You are under confusion because concurrently you are worried about mixed effects models that are used as part of GLM models . ASSUMING that the estimation procedure is correct , you have four  hypotheses to test difference in proportion. Please n for each type of treatment- just want to know for my sake. I failed to import your data in my Dropbox. IF you feel comfortable, please  email it to drsubhashdavar@Gmail.com

Comment: You have said that you are operating under network meta analysis . Please state how the dependent and independent variables have been modelled for your analysis.  Forget for the time being about random effects models..Proportion s have been computed for individual studies and synthesised  with

Comment: @subhash c. davar please see the code at the top of the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61349/discussion-between-subhash-c-davar-and-rotterdam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU have computed pooled proportion for each of five treatments under the assumption of random-effects. These estimates  indicate population effect - sizes . Presuming that the treatment methods are independent, each of four treatments may be compared  with gold -standard treatment (PC) with a view to ascertain whether  a significant difference  exists e.g. between EF and PC  i.e. whether population effect (proportion) for E F is significantly different from population proportion for PC - the  gold standard. The Z- test of difference in population proportions is most appropriate in this case . THE chi- square test does not serve the purpose.

Comment: How do you correct for the multiple comparisons and the statistical dependence of all four tests?

Comment: THE test is comparing each treatment  against Gold standard ? Why do we need checking for interdependence of treatments ?  There is nothing in the question that suggests what you  have presumed..Moreover, the answer clearly indicates that it has been assumed that the treatment- types are independent of each other. Anyhow a good  question. Thanks.

Comment: Four comparisons obviously raise a multiple comparisons issue.  When they are comparisons against a common "pooled" value, they are *a fortiori* interdependent.  These are the two problems ANOVA was designed to address; applying a set of separate tests, as you propose, is invalid.

Comment: I have not proposed anything .The proposal or issues  have been  raised by OP.. There is nothing - like a constant (effect) hypothesis that shall irequire implemenation of meta-analysis. THE erstwhile A NOV A is a poorly designed method  and  hence virtually discarded  .If you can spare time , please read my questions and see me at Google scholar.

Comment: Are you trying to say that your passages "each of four treatments may be compared with gold-standard treatment" and "The Z- test of difference in population proportions is most appropriate in this case" are *not* recommendations or proposals?  What, then, are you trying to communicate to us?  Do you agree with what you have written or not?

Comment: Under the assumption that treatments  are independent and  that OP is not interested in checking that a general hypothesis  of constant effect holds. Please state the statistical problems that we may face if we follow the  procedure. Two or more treatments could have significant effect .